# The type argument for the type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: angular

Im trying to setup a service and I am getting typescript errors concerning types.  What am I missing?

The code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { User } from "app/models/user";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
   constructor(private http: Http) {
   }

   getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
      return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
         .map((res: Response) => res.json())
         .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
   }
}
```

The error:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Build:The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly*

**[update]**
My mistake, the code I copied here wasnt the actual code I was running.  In the import for Http, I had left off the Response class.  Soon as I added that, the problem went away.

Comment: hate to break this to you but the code works fine, i guess the error is some where else. i guess this is more of a VSCode error . please try and update your typescript version

Comment: yes, you are correct:)  my mistake - see update comment

Comment: great work  :)..